# Erro ao listar postagens com node.js e sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Sempre que vou abrir a rota "/" diz `finAll is not a function`, o que está errado?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const Post = require('./models/Post')

    // handlebars
    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars( { defaultLayout: 'main' } ))
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
    // body-parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false } ))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    // rotas
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
            Post.findAll().then( (posts) => {
                    res.render("pages/home", {posts: posts});
            });
    });

    app.get("/postar", (req, res) => {
            res.render('pages/form')
    })

    app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
            Post.create({
                    titulo: req.body.titulo,
                    conteudo: req.body.conteudo
            }).then( () => {
                    res.redirect("/")
            }).catch( (err) => {
                    res.send("Houve um erro: " + err)
            })
    })

    const PORT = 8080
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log("servidor rodando na porta " + PORT)
    })
```

Conteúdo do models/db.js:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize("friendship", "root", "", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql"
});

// Postagem.sync( { force: true } )

module.exports = {
  Sequelize: Sequelize,
  sequelize: sequelize
}
```

Conteúdo do models/Post.js:

```
const db = require('./db')
const Post = db.sequelize.define("postagens", {
  titulo: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING
  },
  conteudo: {
    type: db.Sequelize.TEXT
  }
});

// Post.sync( { force: true } )
```

Comment: Consegue informar o código do seu arquivo `./models/Post`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UB0TZ7Z0

Comment: https://pastebin.com/juMZU3aS

Comment: Não coloque no pastebin. Adicione na sua pergunta, senão ela fica incompleta e corre o risco de ser fechada por falta de informações

Comment: É que emprestei meu adaptador de rede pro meu amigo só por hoje e a internet não está pegando, e daí estou usando o stack pelo celular e não dá para formatar textos :/

Comment: Não tem problema, cola na resposta que eu formato

Comment: Mas consegue saber qual o erro? Garanto que nn seja a internet, pois instalei todos os pacotes necessários

Comment: tá bom espera aí

Comment: const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
"friendship",
"root",
"",
{
        host: "localhost",
        dialect: "mysql"
})

// Postagem.sync( { force: true } )

module.exports = {
        Sequelize: Sequelize,
        sequelize: sequelize
}
~

Comment: const db = require('./db')
const Post = db.sequelize.define("postagens", {
        titulo: {
                type: db.Sequelize.STRING
        },
        conteudo: {
                type: db.Sequelize.TEXT
        }
})

// Post.sync( { force: true } )

Comment: Edita a pergunta e cola nela

Comment: tá indo tudo junto não sei por que, quer esperar até amanhã até eu pegar meu adaptador?

Comment: espera um segundo

Comment: Pronto, aí está kkk

Answer (score 0):

Você não exportou o módulo dentro do arquivo `Post`. No fim do seu arquivo adicione a seguinte linha:

```
module.exports = Post;
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, também passei pelo mesmo problema.

Além de exportar o módulo Post adicionando a linha abaixo no arquivo models/Post.js

```
module.exports = Post
```

Para poder listar os registros da tabela posts na view você precisa configurar a opção `runtimeOptions` com as propriedades `allowProtoPropertiesByDefault` e `allowProtoMethodsByDefault` com valor `true`.

Ficando assim:

```
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    runtimeOptions: {
        allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
        allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true,
    },
}))
```

Espero que consiga resolver.

Abraços.